# How does one keep a user logged in with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django coming from the Firebase world, where authentication and keeping a user logged in is super easy.

In learning Django (Rest Framework) I came to find out that you can log in a user, get a token and save the token in Cookies to reuse is next time that same user goes into the website.  Is this the best way to keep a user logged in?

So far, I can log a user in, get their token and some additional info, but **I'm not sure how to prevent this from happening over and over again**. I'd like to know how to keep the user logged in.

Also, whenever the user gets back on the browser, do I place a POST request to get their own information (if needed to display on the screen)? Always?

I'm very confused as to how authentication/logging in works.

Answer (score 0):

An usual way to handle this problem is to use Jwt auth.

You will issue a short lived token alongside a long lived refresh token to your consumer.

https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt

On your frontend side you can implement an automatic refresh mechanism when the token expire.

Example with React: https://medium.com/@monkov/react-using-axios-interceptor-for-token-refreshing-1477a4d5fc26

On browser side, it's depend. For example with single page app, you can fetch info only one and store them in a store.
For multi page app, you could still use cookie or local storage to persist data.

Answer (score 0):

#### Each Request is anonymous/new, even after you login.

## Why I keep loggedin?

Once you logged in, server usually reuturn a token and save it in your local browser. Next time you send request, you can add the token in your request. Then server will know it is still the same user.

## What is token?

There a many kinds of token: session token, jwt, basic token...
Token is a string of your identity, and jwt(JSON Web Tokens) is one of the most popular authentication(CORS) solution. This is how original jwt looks like:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
```

And this is how actual jwt data looks like:

```
# HEADER:ALGORITHM
{ 
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
# PAYLOAD:DATA
{ 
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "iat": 1516239022
}
# VERIFY SIGNATURE
HMACSHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),
  your-256-bit-secret
)
```

## Where do I keep token

Token is storage in your local cookies. For each request, you can get token from local cookies and add to request head. For example, in React:

```
import Cookies from "universal-cookie"

localCookies = new Cookies();
...
..
fetch(`/api/logs/:id`, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'JWT ' + localCookies.get('token'),
            }
        })
...
..
```